# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1442 Can't update table 'catalog_product_entity_varchar' in stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I am running a MySql Trigger, and want to update the value of the attribute 260, I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1442 Can't update table 'catalog_product_entity_varchar' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger., query was: UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` SET `value` = ? WHERE (entity_id = 6779) AND (attribute_id = '260') AND (`store_id` = '0')

From the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER change_network_ebay BEFORE UPDATE ON catalog_product_entity_varchar
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
IF NEW.attribute_id = '260' THEN  
   UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar 
   SET NEW.value = '4G/LTE' where entity_id = NEW.entity_id AND NEW.attribute_id= 260 ;
END IF;
END;
```

And this is how my database looks like:

[image]

[image]

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: It''s a pity your sample screen shot doesn't include examples of attribute_id  260 - how many 260s are there by the way?

Comment: In a MySQL trigger, the only row you are allowed to modify (in the table the trigger is defined for) is the row you just updated/inserted. If you intend to update more than one row, you may need to find a workaround (e.g. do it from the outside, or normalize your data), if you actually just want to update the row you just updated, you just need to fix your code. You would need to provide this detail.

Comment: @P.Salmon Sorry I am new here. I just update a new image with all attrbiteu_Id 260 ,could you please help me to check it?

Comment: @Solarflare, the row I want to update the value is the row that just updated.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. The update seems to be setting the value, why would you want to do it again in the trigger?